# SQL Convert one column into two based on another column

Tags: sql, select, pivot, where-clause, multiple-columns

With the following Data Set:

```
Extender_Record_ID: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5
Field_ID: 100, 101, 100, 101, 100, 101, 100, 101, 100, 101
Date: 1/1/2018, 1/2/2018, 1/14/2018, 1/15/2018, 2/1/2018, 2/3/2018, 
      2/15/2018, 2/17/2018, 3/2/2018, 3/5/2018
```

I am trying to get an output of:

```
Start Date: 1/1/2018, 1/14/2018, 2/1/2018, 2/15/2018, 3/2/2018  
End Date: 1/2/2018, 1/15/2018, 2/3/2018, 2/17/2018, 3/5/2018
```

I am trying to split the date column into two separate date columns based on the value in the ID column. I want to insert this into a larger query.

Sorry, I'm new to this. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `MIN()`, `MAX()`.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select extendedrecordid, field_id, max(case when field_id = 1 then date else null end )date1,
max(case when field_id = 2 then date else null end )date2
from yourtable group by extendedrecordid, field_id
```

Comment: I have approximately a thousand rows of Dates that all correspond to to either ID 1 or ID 2. I got the min and max query to produce what i needed for the minor example. Is there something that works better for many rows? I might be doing this completely wrong also :(

Comment: Please show more of your expected results and Ill rework the query for you

Comment: I'm still not getting it right. Let me post an answer with more data. I can't seem to do it here in the comments. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: OK also please show the sample data in table form like you originally did

Answer (score 0):

It it's as simple as one always being the `min` and the other being the `max`, you could just do:

```
SELECT MIN(DATE) AS Date1
     , MAX(DATE) AS Date2
  FROM ...
GROUP BY ID
```

Or maybe something more complicated with a pivot, but we would probably need to know the SQL flavor for that

Comment: I have approximately a thousand rows of Dates that all correspond to to either ID 1 or ID 2. I got the min and max query to produce what i needed for the minor example. Is there something that works better for many rows? I might be doing this completely wrong also :(

Comment: Can you add a couple more rows of input/output, and put them in the format they were in before, so I can get more of an idea, if you're only differentiating by 1 or 2, it might not be possible to differentiate

Answer (score 0):

What you probably actually need, based on your comment `I got the min and max query to produce what i needed for the minor example.` is something like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN [DateField] END AS Date1, 
CASE WHEN Id = 2 THEN [DateField] END AS Date2
FROM [MyTable]
```